# no start action in debug VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, npgsql

I am trying to use DDEX for npgsql. while following steps provided  http://fxjr.blogspot.fr/2011/05/npgsql-design-time-support-preview.html I came across a problem. The steps specifies that after setting up the project to startup project. I should go to the debug option and select start action to external program. But the problem is I cannot see the option for that. below is the screen shot of what I get when I select debug in project properties.

[image]

Is there any way around to get the project debug in another instance of devenv.exe to complete my DDEX npgsql setup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This debug option is not available in VS Express.

The way around this is to manually edit the `*.csproj.user` file in your project folder, and add the following `PropertyGroup`:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram>C:\Path\To\program.exe</StartProgram>
    <StartArguments>/Something</StartArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

You will need to make sure that the Configuration and Platform (Debug|x86 in my example) match yours.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did that but I am having 100s of error while debugging. I am not sure if you could help me in the error. The error states "The name 'VSConstants' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I think it would be best for you to accept this answer, and create a new question with the details of what you're doing, and the exact error messages.